# Display some items in Bold in ComboBox

Tags: winforms

I have a combobox in my windows application which is DataBound to a readonly list.My requirement is to show some of the items in Bold based on a property of the list. The property is different from that of value member and Display Member. Is there anyway to do it without looping through each of the item, as the list is too big?

Answer (score 2):

Key off of the selected item.

```
public Form1()
{
    _dataItems = new List<DataItem>
        {
            new DataItem {Name = "Alpha", IsBold = true, OtherData = new object()},
            new DataItem {Name = "Beta", IsBold = false, OtherData = new object()},
            new DataItem {Name = "Gamma", IsBold = true, OtherData = new object()},
        };

    this.InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DrawItem += comboBox1_DrawItem;

    comboBox1.DataSource = _dataItems;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "OtherData";
}

void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = (DataItem)comboBox1.Items[e.Index];

    if (dataItem.IsBold)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dataItem.Name, BoldFont, SystemBrushes.ControlText,
                            e.Bounds);
    else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dataItem.Name, NormalFont, SystemBrushes.ControlText,
                            e.Bounds);
}
```

The DataItem class:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsBold { get; set; }
    public Object OtherData { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: var dataItem = (DataItem) comboBox1.Items[e.Index]; Is it possible to access the items collection before binding the data to the control? The datasource is assigned after the above line.

Comment: @bhu I have changed the code to use traditional functions instead of LINQ